# Bid and Ask Data for european stocks

Tags: data

I am working on something to analyze European stocks and I need some historical data on bid and ask prices. Ideally I would like something like CRSP database for US stocks. Is there some similar source or database for European stocks? I spent hours on google but didn't find anything useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get historical end-of-day European Bid Ask Data with Datastream ( Symbol BID, ASK) and also with Bloomberg ( Symbols: PX_BID, PX_ASK).These are daily closing bid and ask prices.

Note that Bloomberg also offers **intraday** bid ask data for the last 140 days.

Comment: Thanks, And how back into history the data from Datastream go?

Comment: for datastream and European data: you can get data from the 1980s but  there is a lot of missing values and outliers. Starting from 2000, bid ask prices are far more reliable.